# Can't explain why cd works and its absolute path does not, on centos 7

Tags: command-line-interface, centos7

I'm on a CentOS Linux release 7.7.1908 (Core).
From cli, typing:

```
~ which cd
```

gives

```
~ /bin/cd
```

Take the case I am on **/home**. If I type

```
~ cd ..
```

I go back to root folder **/**.

But if I do

```
~ /bin/cd ..
```

it does nothing. I still find myself in **/home**.

What can it be?

Answer (score 0):

`cd` is a shell internal, i.e the shell handles the changing of the directory itself. the default action of the shell internal version of `cd` is to say where you are, logically. In other words, if you `cd` to a symbolic link, `cd` will report the symbolic link name, not the actual directory. You can change this by going `cd -P`.

`/usr/bin/cd` is a binary that changes your working directory. Its default behavior is to show you the real directory you are in.

The only real purpose of `/usr/bin/cd` is to be able to `exec` the command in order to get the exit code to find out if it's possible to change to a directory.